# Latex template for the MHRA Author-Date style of referencing

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf, templates

My department uses the MHRA Author-Date style of referencing, and I am planning to use Overleaf to write my dissertation.

Does anyone know where can I find the template of the MHRA Author-Date style? Thank you very much.